# Body parser is showing undefined in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules, body-parser

The body parser is showing as undefined when i am sending the data through the url.

This is the url : `http://localhost:3011/mybooking?email=example@example.com`

Here is my code :

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('*',(req,res)=>
{

    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.body.email)
    console.log(req.params.email)
 })

const port = 3011
app.listen(port,(req,res)=>
{
    console.log("App.js listening on the port "+port)
})
```

please do help me at your earliest.

my output is

```
App.js listening on the port 3011
{}
undefined
undefined
```

Comment: Have you tried without the `urlencoded` line?

Comment: In the browser do you get any error ?

Comment: i have tried the isssue was i had to use req.query.email.

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables passed in the URL are retrieved using **req.query**.

In your case to get the value of email, you need to retrieve using req.query.email.

req.body is used when the data is passed through the body (basically a post request)

req.params is used when data is passed using dynamic variables.

eg. http://localhost:3011/book/:id   --->   req.params.id